# Cocos2D Undefined symbols for architecture i386 after updating Googles adMob to 6.12.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, admob, i386

At first, everything worked fine. But after Google AdMob SDK update all damaged and can not figure out how to solve this problem:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: 
   "_OBJC_CLASS _ $ _ EKEvent, referenced from: 
       objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a (GADOpener.o) 
   "_OBJC_CLASS _ $ _ EKEventEditViewController, referenced from: 
       objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a (GADOpener.o) 
ld: symbol (s) not found for architecture i386 
Clangers: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding the EventKit.framework and the EventKitUI.framework to my project

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent almost two days in search of solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@rainworf 's answer is true. The reason is that you gotta link the necessary framework for the Google AdMob SDK

Finally I find it from [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start#_adc=ww-en-et-developers_sdk) link, which includes `EventKit.framework` and `EventKitUI.framework`:

> The SDK library references the following iOS development frameworks which may not already be part of your project:
>
> - AdSupport
> - AudioToolbox
> - AVFoundation
> - CoreGraphics
> - CoreTelephony
> - EventKit
> - EventKitUI
> - MessageUI
> - StoreKit
> - SystemConfiguration